# Combining OAuth with Active Directory for authentication

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth, active-directory, single-sign-on

We have angular front end which works with WebApi backend and we have used OAUTH(Bearer token) as mode of authentication.

Everything is working fine as expected.

Now we have a requirement where one of the clients wants to verify the already logged in user(Active Directory) and let them In skipping the login, the users already exist in our database as well.

We want to keep the entire OAUTH mechanism the same but add an extra step where we check if the current logged in user(Active Directory) matches with our db user(email in that case) then we generate a token and let client in without the need to give usename/password every time they want to log in.

Any ideas on how to achieve this and any code examples will be helpful.

If you need any more explanation they please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can store the token returned from the server after the initial login. Then In all subsequent requests include the token in the request header.

For example

Authorization: Bearer 0b79bab50daca910b000d4f1a2b675d604257e42

Comment: that is normal OAuth behaviour which is already working as I mentioned in my question. how does this relate to my question which is authenticating ActiveDirectory user?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Do need to authenticate the user just in the beginning using Active directory or you want to check the user existence in the DB in each request?

Comment: Also another question. Form where do you access your application, Is it from the internet or local network?

Comment: The user is already logged in to the machine(AD) and the site is hosted in intranet. If they come to the site it should not ask for login since they are already logged in, they site should check whether the logged in user(AD user) exist in database if it does it generates token and let user in without needing for login details. Does that explain?

Comment: If the user already logged in then you can access his/her identity using the  follwing "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name"  then you can compare it to your stored value in the database

Comment: Or "HttpContext.User.Identity.Name"

Comment: It wont work this method will only work after authentication is done on webapi. It might work in case where authentication mode is windows while I am using OAuth with bearer token.